# Limit std::filebuf to file inside (archive) file

Tags: c++, iostream, streambuf

I am currently implementing a custom `std::filebuf` which reads files from uncompressed .zip archives. For each file in the archive I have the offset into the archive file and the size. Now I want to limit the filebuf to the interval `[offset, offset+size]` so that I can use functions like `pubseekoff()` as if I have opened a normal file. For example when i do `pubseekoff(5, std::ios::beg, std::ios::in);` the filebuf should actually set it's underlying get-pointer to `offset+5` in the archive file.

What would be the best way of implementing this? I tried to derive from `std::filebuf` and override functions like `seekoff()` to do the local file offset -> archive file offset conversions but that didn't work since the underlying filebuf (wich doesn't know anything about my archive-offsets) calls these functions and throws eof errors and the like. I also tried to derive from `std::streambuf` and *use* a `std::filebuf` inside my streambuf, but that also didn't work since most members in `std::streambuf` are protected. I *could* use a `std::ifstream` inside my streambuf but that seems to be cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rewriting a streambuf from scratch. It uses the C-Style fopen(), fread() etc. functions. The code is not very well tested (neither for correctness nor for performance) but it works for me:

http://pastebin.com/Bt4rh0mu